# Is there way to tell WinDbg to ignore program breakpoints?

Tags: windbg

Is there way to tell WinDbg to ignore program breakpoints like caused by [DebugBreak function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at the [Controlling Exceptions and Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page on MSDN. It explains how to use the `sx*` commands to break, ignore, or print exceptions/events as they happen.

What you are looking for is probably:

```
sxn bpe
```

This tells the debugger to print a message without breaking when a breakpoint exception (0x80000003) occurs.

Typical debugger output looks like:

```
(b70.11fc): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
```

Comment: and how to disable program breakpoint at a specific line in code?